# Struts html:button equivalent

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, struts2

I'm migrating from struts to spring and I'm currently stuck figuring out what the struts `html:button` does.

Specifically the `property` value. According to [this doc](https://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/button.html) the property is 'Name of the request parameter that will be included with this submission, set to the specified value. '

The actual line is

`<html:button property="doCall" onClick="javascript:void(validate());" value="Generate New"/>`

I haven't found a spring forms button equivalent. 
But would an `<input type="button" onClick="javascript:void(validate());"  id="doCall" name="doCall"/>` work? Slightly confused what the property is

Comment: Looks promising. Have you tried it?

Comment: Why not just look at what's rendered and sent?